# Finding the exact value of $\tan(\cos^{-1} x)$

Tags: trigonometry

> Find the exact values of:
>     a) $\tan(\cos^{-1} x)$
>     b) $\cos(\tan^{-1} x)$
>     c) $\sec(\sin^{-1} x)$

My work is the following.

a) $\tan x = \sin x / \cos x$ so

$$\tan(\cos^{-1} x) = \sin(\cos^{-1} x) / \cos(\cos^{-1} x) = \sin(\cos^{-1}x) / x$$

b) $\cos(\tan^{-1} x) = \cos(\sin^{-1} x / \cos^{-1} x)$

c) $\sec(\sin^{-1} x)= 1/\cos(\sin^{-1} x)$

Is my answer correct?

Comment: $\tan^{-1} x = \sin^{-1} x / \cos^{-1} x$ is wrong. Check the identities about $\arctan x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Useful things to note
$$
\tan^2 x + 1 = \sec^2 x \implies \tan x = \pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{\cos^2 x}-1}
$$
And
$$
\cos^2 x+\sin^2 x = 1\implies \cos x =\pm\sqrt{1-\sin^2 x}
$$
Can you use these to your advantage?

Answer (score 0):

$\tan(\cos^{-1}x)=\frac {\sin(\cos^{-1}x)}{x} = \frac {\sqrt {1-x^2}}{x}$ using the identity $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$

Likewise, you can simplify other expressions too.